# Set Parent directive's property from child directive in angular 1.3

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

We have a third party control directive and a custom directive inside that directive.This is the HTML.

```
<thirdpartydirective custom-directive ng-model="myCtrl.newCount" </thirdpartydirective>
```

We are using angular 1.3 and using controllerAs syntax for the controller.
Custom directive appends a button to the thirdpartydirective and on click of that button we want to change the value of myCtrl.newCount.

Is possible to achieve this in the custom directive code itself without making a call to  the underlying controller's method.
I am able to use $compile inside the directive and bind the method, and the method is correctly calling the controller's method.

But i am wondering if we can set the third party directive's property(myCtrl.newCount) from the custom directive code itself.

Comment: At glance your description, I think `myCtrl.newCount` is your controller scope value, is **NOT** the third party directive's property. Therefore as you have already done, I believe that calling the controller's method is right way.

Comment: The solution mostly depends on both of your directives, more specific code would be great.